# Move Elasticsearch data folder to Maven target

Tags: maven, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

In my Spring Boot 1.5.1 application I have added Elasticsearch Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

During application startup ES created `{project.dir}/data/elasticsearch` folder.

Please show how to reconfigure ES to create this folder at `{project.dir}/target/data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fond the solution, place the following properties into application.properties file:

```
#Elasticsearch
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.path.data=target/data
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.path.logs=target/logs
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you configure your `elasticsearch.yml` by uncommenting the **path.data** line and changing it to the respective directory:

```
path.data: target/data
```